# How to check the XML properties of dynamically created widgets in runtime?

Tags: android

I am tinkering with dynamically created UI's at the moment and it becomes difficult to know if the properties I gave to a widget were actually applied in runtime. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
 public void createButton () {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layoutId.addview(button);
        System.out.println(button.getLayoutParams);
    }
```

This hopefully prints `android:layout_width:MATCH_PARENT` and `android:layout_height:MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: That won't compile, as `getLayoutParams()` [is a method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams()), not a field. And I do not know whether that particular `LayoutParams` class has a useful `toString()` for logging. But... what is your question?

Comment: I want to print, in runtime, the values of XML fields like margins and width from programatically created widgets like buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Call `getLayoutParams()` on the `View` that you are interested in.

Step #2: Cast that to the proper type (e.g., `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`)

Step #3: Log whatever values from that object that you want to LogCat (e.g., `Log.d()`)